# How do I print 8 decimals in php

Tags: php

if i have a number:

```
$num = 0.00638835;
```

which is an average of 100 entries.  I want to find the average and print it.

```
$avg = $num/100;
```

my result prints as:

```
echo $avg;

6.38835E-5
```

how can i print it as:

```
 .000004928 //or whatever the number is
```

Comment: echo $avg and echo floatval($avg)

Comment: We are always glad to help and support new coders but ***you need to help yourself first. :-)*** After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_number_format.asp

```
$num = 0.00638835;
$avg = $num/100;
echo number_format ($avg, 8);
```

0.00006388

Answer (score 0):

`echo number_format($a, 10);`
with number format you can select any number of decimals

Answer (score 0):

$num = 0.00638835;

$avg = $num/100;

echo number_format($avg, 8);